# Set shortcut for command Debug.DisableAllBreakpoints

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using VS2015. I would like to have shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> for disabling all breakpoints. It should be easy, but under Environment - Keyboard after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> I have only limited amount of choices to pick from. Is it possible to set this shortcut to command Debug.DisableAllBreakpoints?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That bottom list is not your set of choices...it is what is currently assigned to the key sequence you are trying to use.

If you click "Assign", the key sequence should be assigned to your command and *overwrite* the sequence in the commands in the bottom list, i.e. remove the shortcut from those commands.